# Sufficient Statisitics and Discrete Distributions

Tags: sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics, discrete-distributions

I am trying to master minimal/complete sufficient statistics, however I am having trouble when the distributions are discrete and involve indicator functions. Here is my 3 part question:

Let $X$ be a random variable from the following distribution:
$$f(x;\theta) = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} \theta & , & x = -1 \\ 1 - 2\theta & , & x = 0 \\ \theta & , & x = 1\end{array}\right.$$

where $0\leq \theta \leq\frac{1}{2}$.

1. Find a minimal sufficient statistic for parameter $\theta$.

**Answer**: Define the indicator functions:
$$I_1(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & , & x = -1 \\ 0 & , & {\rm otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$
$$I_2(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & , & x = 0 \\ 0 & , & {\rm otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$
$$I_3(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & , & x = 1 \\ 0 & , & {\rm otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

Then,
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x;\theta) & = & (\theta)^{I_1(x)}(1 - 2\theta)^{I_2(x)}(\theta)^{I_3(x)} \\
& = & \theta^{I_1(x) + I_3(x)}(1 - 2\theta)^{I_2(x)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Therefore, by the Factorization Theorem, a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ is:
$$T(\underline{X}) = (I_1(x) + I_3(x), I_2(x))$$

To show that this is a minimum:
$$\frac{f(x;\theta)}{f(y;\theta)} = \frac{\theta^{I_1(x) + I_3(x)}(1 - 2\theta)^{I_2(x)}}{\theta^{I_1(y) + I_3(y)}(1 - 2\theta)^{I_2(y)}}$$

is independent of $\theta$ if and only if $I_1(x) + I_3(x) = I_1(y) + I_3(y)$ and $I_2(x) = I_2(y)$. Therefore, $T(\underline{X})$ is a minimal sufficient statistic.

2. Is $X$ a complete statistic?

**Answer**: By definition I know I need to show $E[u(z)] = 0$ implies $u(z) = 0$ for all $\theta$. However, I am unsure how to show $X$ is complete.

3. From Part 1, is the statistic complete? Why?

**Answer**: Once again I understand the definition of complete, but am unsure on how to reach the conclusion based on:
\begin{eqnarray*}
E[u(z)] & = & 0 \\
\sum\limits_{z = -1}^1 u(z)\theta^{I_1(z) + I_3(z)}(1 - 2\theta)^{I_2(z)} & = & 0
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I do not think your proposal is a minimum (if the sample size is fixed and known)

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

The minimal sufficient partition is

$$\{ \{-1,1\}, \{0\} \} $$

(since $\frac{f_\theta(1)}{f_\theta(-1)}$ does not depend on $\theta$).

So the minimal sufficient statistics(MSS) is

\begin{eqnarray}
S(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
a & x=0 \\
b & x=-1,1
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}

Is it a complete statistics?

$\forall \theta\in(0,\frac{1}{2})$

\begin{eqnarray}
0=E(g(S(X))) &=& g(b)\theta +g(a) (1-2\theta )+g(b)\theta \\
&=& g(a)+\left(g(b)-2g(a)+g(b)\right) \theta
\\
&=& g(a)+2\left(g(b)-g(a)\right) \theta
\end{eqnarray}

So you can easily check it.

Comment: @Xi'an, Thanks, It is corrected.